# android softkeyboard key pressed event

Tags: android

I have created custom keyboard in which I set below property.
I want to change key image while it pressed, as we do with button in same way.
how can I change key icon while it pressed?

```
 <Row>
        <Key
            android:id="@+id/key1"
            android:codes="8"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/k1" />
        <Key
            android:codes="9"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/k2hover"
             android:keyIcon="@drawable/k2" />
        <Key
            android:codes="10"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/k3hover"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
             android:keyIcon="@drawable/k3" />
    </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a :

```
row.setOnKeyPressed(new OnKeyPressed() {
    //Add the unimplemented methods
});
```

Comment: how to create row object and in which file I can get row object?1. class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener 2.class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView

Comment: Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view.
It doesn't work for soft keyboards.